# Writing Canbus commands to keypad using Arduino Canbus shield by seeed studion

Tags: arduino, can-bus

So I am using my seeed studio canbus shield on my arduino uno. I had two goals, the first was to read data from a keypad and the second was to write commands to it to make LED lights change colors and turn off and on. I was able to use the seeed studio code to read data off of the controller easy, but I cant figure out how to get my commands to the keypad.

below is the code I am using, also from the seed studio library

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define CAN_2515
// #define CAN_2518FD

// Set SPI CS Pin according to your hardware

#if defined(SEEED_WIO_TERMINAL) && defined(CAN_2518FD)
// For Wio Terminal w/ MCP2518FD RPi Hat：
// Channel 0 SPI_CS Pin: BCM 8
// Channel 1 SPI_CS Pin: BCM 7
// Interupt Pin: BCM25
const int SPI_CS_PIN  = BCM8;
const int CAN_INT_PIN = BCM25;
#else

// For Arduino MCP2515 Hat:
// the cs pin of the version after v1.1 is default to D9
// v0.9b and v1.0 is default D10
const int SPI_CS_PIN = 9;
const int CAN_INT_PIN = 2;
#endif


#ifdef CAN_2518FD
#include "mcp2518fd_can.h"
mcp2518fd CAN(SPI_CS_PIN); // Set CS pin
#endif

#ifdef CAN_2515
#include "mcp2515_can.h"
mcp2515_can CAN(SPI_CS_PIN); // Set CS pin
#endif

void setup() {
    SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR.begin(250000);
    while(!Serial){};

    while (CAN_OK != CAN.begin(CAN_250KBPS)) {             // init can bus : baudrate = 250k
        SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR.println("CAN init fail, retry...");
        delay(100);
    }
    SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR.println("CAN init ok!");
}

unsigned char stmp[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
void loop() {
    // send data:  id = 0x00, standrad frame, data len = 8, stmp: data buf
    stmp[7] = stmp[7] + 1;
    if (stmp[7] == 100) {
        stmp[7] = 0;
        stmp[6] = stmp[6] + 1;

        if (stmp[6] == 100) {
            stmp[6] = 0;
            stmp[5] = stmp[5] + 1;
        }
    }

    CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x00, 0, 8, stmp);
    delay(100);                       // send data per 100ms
    SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR.println("CAN BUS sendMsgBuf ok!");
}

// END FILE
```

[Here is a copy of the commands I am trying to send to the keypad, the commands come from the documentation I got with the keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63a6w.png)

Answer (score 0):

The can-matrix that you attach says that the Keypad has an ID of 215, most likely `0x215` ( in hex) and you are sending a message with an ID of 0x00. The keypad won't respond to it.

change the send message to:

```
    CAN.sendMsgBuf(0x215, 0, 8, stmp);
```

CAN is an ID-priority based protocol, lower ID's have a higher priority. Lower numbers are used for critical messages like errors and faults.  As a rule of thumb, ID 0x00 is not used.

Now, depending on what Colors you want to see, you will have to put the proper values on the `stmp` array